# What is the difference between ConfidentialClientApplication and a PublicClientApplication?

Tags: .net-core, azure-ad-msal

I'm putting together a web service that provides a RESTful API.  I've built a UWP client that uses a **PublicClientApplication** and it works pretty well.  Now I'm building a Web Application to also speak to the same service and the examples I've found use the **ConfidentialClientApplication** to acquire access tokens for the user.  So what is the difference between the two classes that both seem to produce access tokens (documentation is very light to non-existent) and what are the use cases between the to classes.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

While looking into MSAL myself I managed to find some documentation for [MSAL.net](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki) including a [chapter](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Client-Applications) about Client applications.

It explicitly talks about the differences between the **Confidential client application class** and the **Public client application class**.

**Confidential Client**

> Confidential client applications are typically applications which run on servers (Web 
>   Apps, Web API, or even service/daemon applications). They are
>   considered difficult to access, and therefore capable of keeping an
>   application secret. Confidential clients are able to hold
>   configuration time secrets. Each instance of the client has a distinct
>   configuration (including clientId and secret). These values are
>   difficult for end users to extract. A web app is the most common
>   confidential client. The clientId is exposed through the web browser,
>   but the secret is passed only in the back channel and never directly
>   exposed.

**Public Client**

> On the contrary public client applications are typically applications
>   which run on devices (phones for instance) or desktop machines. They
>   are not trusted to safely keep application secrets, and therefore
>   access Web APIs in the name of the user only (they only support public
>   client flows). Public clients are unable to hold configuration time
>   secrets, and as a result have no client secret